# Page not redirecting, php

Tags: php

Page is not redirecting to the login screen when session value not set. I have echo the value and checked. Session value not exists, even then page not redirecting following is my code.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Why not add a `var_dump($_SESSION)` in there to see what's actually set?

Comment: [Do you have error reporting on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)? are you getting any notices? Possibly related: [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Comment: If your page is not redirecting, what is it doing? Stay in the same page? Shows blank screen?

Comment: i have done that value of session['user'] is 1

Comment: it is staying in the same page

Comment: Your code only jumps to index when $_SESSION is not set (`if(!isset`), but $_SESSION is set to 1, so it doesn't jump to index.

Comment: it doesn't jumps to index. no matter what

Answer (score 0):

I do this slightly differently.  Here is a snippet I use.  I try to stay away from !isset when I can use the empty instead.

```
if (empty($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("location: ./index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like mando222 said, using dynamic URL.
Better practice is to set the full URL to the header. Optionally show us your project folders so we can see where you are and where you'd like to go.

Use `var_dump($_SESSION);` can help us to.